# QQ plot result doesn't correspond to normality test

Tags: r, regression, anova

I am considering an ANOVA model for such data:

```
Student    Class  Points on exam   Day of studying
1           P1       12             Day 10
2           P3       23             Day 5
3           P3       8              Day 1
4           P2       36             Day 10
5           P1       10             Day 1
6           P2       86             Day 10
7           P1       13             Day 5
```

and such ANOVA model:

```
model <- aov(Points ~ Class + Day, data)
```

how can I check if this model **satisfies the normality of distribution?** (other than the Q-Q plot of the model?)

[image: QQ-plot]

**My Q-Q plot of the model (above) seems to show normal distribution but when I perform Shapiro-Wilk( that considers only Points) the p-value comes out incredibly small... Therefore I don't know if I can assume the normality or not.**

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  Points
W = 0.92212, p-value = 9.97e-13
```

Comment: I recommend you to post this question to another Stack Exchange community that specialise in statistics called [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). Also, you are encouraged to share as much data as possible that you are testing the normality so that other people could replicate your attempt and suggest any solution.

Comment: As to the low p-value, the null hypothesis of the Shapiro Wilk test is that the population (data) is normally distributed. Assuming common (0.05) or even aggressive p-values (may depend on your volume of data, a bit lower than 0.05), your `9.97e-13` suggests that your data is _not_ normally distributed. The tails show symmetry but do look a bit "off".